# PHP not able to retrieve request.send

Tags: javascript, php

I am a novice in PHP and Javascript, and I am having some difficulties sending Google map bounds to a PHP that runs a SQL to find addresses within the bounds and generates an XML used to place markers.

I got some help to clean up my code, but the problem persists. The problem is either that my Javascript is not sending data to the PHP, or that the PHP is not reading the data in the proper manner.

PHP stops if I inlude this line (not actually being used yet in the PHP-file, other than this line:

```
$South = $_POST['South'];
```

Javascript function (North, South, East and West are defined and populated earlier in the js-file. Inserting alert(South) works, so I don't think that is the problem),

```
function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = !window.XMLHttpRequest? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest; //changed this line to select the XMLHttpRequest by default and not use the activeX version when XMLHttpRequest is available.

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };
  request.open('POST', url, true);
  request.send('South='+South+'&North='+North+'&West='+West+'&East='+East);
}
```

Comment: first checked your request is going or not is there error in console. if not request goes properly etc.

Comment: Check you developer console for `POST` variables to check either request is going or not and put `print_r($_POST);` at first line of php file where you sending ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Add `request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` after `request.open('POST', url, true);`

It should be like this:

```
request.open('POST', url, true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.send('South='+South+'&North='+North+'&West='+West+'&East='+East);
```

And replace `if (request.readyState == 4) {` with 
`if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {`

Then it will work.